# Display labels for desired vertices only

Tags: r, plot, label, vertex-attributes

I only want to show labels for the vertices that have a degree greater than 50. I've tried the following code :

`plot(g, vertex.label=(V(g)$id[which(degree > 50)]))`

But rather than only labeling the desired vertices, it seems to relabel all vertices using only the labels for those with a degree greater than 50.

How can I display a plot that only labels the desired vertices? Or is there a way to hide the undesired labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that the length of the vertex.label vector needs to equal the number of vertices. Perhaps something like

```
plot(g, vertex.label=ifelse(degree(g) > 50, V(g)$id, NA) )
```